# Menu with Image in Joomla

Tags: joomla

Hy!!

I am new to joomla. I have to rebuild http://www.bern.ch/weiche_de for school.

I want to build the menu like this:

[image]

My actuall Menu looks like:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Pls add the code you have tried

Comment: i added a menu to my dreamsquare template

Comment: you should go and edit the css file to suit your needs

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (this is not a programming question). Please support the [Joomla proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) on area51 if you'd like a dedicated Joomla equivalent of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do **anything**, **at all**, go read the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), then read **everything** you can find at [w3schools](http://w3schools.com). Last, but **NOT** least, learn to use proper spelling and punctuation.

Having said that, here's something hacked together that probably won't work as you want:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="127.0.0.1/myimage.image" alt="Nothing." />
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Stadtverwaltung</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gemeinderat</a></li>
            <!-- Fill in the rest here -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

then, in your *.css-file, do something like this:

```
.logo {
    float: left;
}
.menu {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Friends don't send friends to W3schools (see http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: W3schools might not be the best source of accurate information, but the very reason they're big is because the very simple 1-2-3-structure of the content (which imo any wiki or similar absolutely fail at). I'd rather have some-what misinformed, but productive beginners than beginners giving up.